# WebXR device API button to enable WebXR in Vision Pro does not exist in my Vision Pro Simulator setting

Tags: webxr, vision-pro

As all the instructions says to WebXR device API button on to make WebXR available.

I don't find any WebXR device API button in my setting

Nor my colleague has the option.

Is this just us experiencing a weird omission?

Anyone out there experiencing the same thing?

Run Vision Pro Simulator from Xcode.

Then run the Vision Pro browser to run any webXR applications.

For example this.

https://3d.camilleworld.com/b/basic

This runs beautifully in Vision Pro Simulator,

but it doesn't turn into the entire screen into VR mode as it should be.

It stays in a small rectangle in the middle.

The web tutorial says we need to set WebXR device API button on,

but just button is missing in Safari setting.

Anyone having the same issue?